# how to make a 'modified' ArrayList thread safe in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am implementing a distributed mutex, and I need to keep track of all the requests that have been made.

I've a message class which is comparable and I've a modified ArrayList

```
requestList = new ArrayList<Message>() {
public synchronized boolean add(Message msg) {
    boolean ret = super.add(msg);
    Collections.sort(requestList);
    return ret;
}
```

I suspect that this `requestList` is getting modified by two threads and I'm seeing elements at the top of the list which should not be there. how do I make this `requestList` thread safe?

would doing as follows work?

```
requestList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Message>() {
public synchronized boolean add(Message msg) {
    boolean ret = super.add(msg);
    Collections.sort(requestList);
    return ret;
});
```

also how does Collection.synchronizedList work? by sort of putting a 'synchronized' for all the methods of the ArrayList?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: well, its difficult to reproduce the bug. it comes up rarely,I've made the change haven't had the issue still.

Comment: Hmmm. idk what to say... Also, you can usually find the `.java` files for the various Java classes somewhere in your JDK installation and/or IDE and/or some online services somewhere.

Comment: bugs still there. Hmm i'll try looking at some implementations.

Comment: Could you use a `TreeMap` instead of an `ArrayList`? That way everything will be sorted for you without you having to call `Collections.sort()` every time you add something. In addition, you'll get better performance. You'll still have to synchronize somehow... What operations are you performing on this collection?

Comment: Why aren't you using one of the concurrent collections?

Comment: I would use a PriorityBlockingQueue. It's thread safe and automatically sorts its elements.

Comment: With the code using `Collections.synchronizedList`, the `synchronized` modifier on `add` is redundant.

Comment: @user3580294 - If he wants a list, then no.  And the indications are that he wants a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would doing as follows work?

No.

Your custom `add` method is synchronizing on a different object to the `requestList` object is using to synchronize.  Hence, there won't be mutual exclusion.

There is a `Collections.synchronizedList` method overload that takes a mutex object as an extra parameter.  Unfortunately, it is declared as package private, so you won't be able to use it.

> so, how do I have a list which IS thread safe, and maintains the sorted order on each add?

There is no simple solution, but a couple of approaches that would work are:

- Change your code so that the `requestList` object is private.  Implement all access to the list via wrapper methods ... and declare them as `synchronized`.
- Write your own custom synchronized list wrapper that can synchronizes on a mutex that is provided to it.  Then instantiate the wrapper with your `this` object as the mutex; i.e. the object that your `add` method is synchronizing on.

Assuming that your `add` method is actually part of a "sorted list" wrapper class, the first option is the best one.

The suggestion of using a `PriorityBlockingQueue` as an alternative to a `List` is a good one, though you do lose some of the methods that you get in the `List` API.  (For example, you can't do index-based operations on a `Queue` ...)

Comment: "Your custom add method is synchronizing on a different object to the requestList object is using to synchronize. Hence, there won't be mutual exclusion." - the synchronizedList wrapper (`requestList`) and the actual list might be synchronizing on different objects, and so the `synchronized` modifier of `add` is useless here, but that doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: @immibis - Actually it does mean that it won't work.  The sort operation is going to be performed without locking to prevent updates to `requestList` happening simultaneously.  The net result is that those updates could be lost.  (Look at how `sort` works ... )

Comment: something calls `requestList.add`, which is synchronized and calls the OP's `add` which calls `Collections.sort`. `requestList`'s monitor is held during the call.

Comment: With the code as written, `requestList.add` CANNOT call the `add` method that the OP has shown us.  Your scenario makes no sense.

Comment: `requestList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Message>() {public synchronized boolean add(Message msg) {...}})` - either I horribly misunderstand what Collections.synchronizedList does, or you're wrong, or my reasoning is faulty.